# How to use MSBuild with TFS for SSIS Build

Tags: tfs, ssis, msbuild

I want to automate my SSIS build and deployments and create a build definition which will build and deploy my SSIS project whenever I queue it up.

I found this project:  http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/82369

which allows you to create a DLL which you can place in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`

Then you can call the SSIS.MSBuild.proj (See end for this) with certain parameters like this in a visual studio command line:

```
MSBuild SSIS.MSBuild.proj /t:SSISBuild,SSISDeploy /p:SSISProj="MySSISProject",Configuration="DEV",,SSISServer="AB-CDE-FGH-I1\DEV",ProjectName="MySSISProject"
```

or I can put it in a BAT file like this:

```
%systemroot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe SSIS.MSBuild.proj /t:SSISBuild,SSISDeploy /p:SSISProj="MySSISProject",Configuration="DEV",,SSISServer="AB-CDE-FGH-I1\DEV",ProjectName="MySSISProject"
```

It works fine when you run the BAT file, it builds and deploys the SSIS project.

Questions:

1. How can I use this so it is automated, so I can manually kick off a build and deployment from within VS/TFS?  Using a build definition.
2. How can I ensure the correct configurations are selected, and the correct destination server?  For example we have SSIS configurations for DEV, SIT, SYS, UAT, PRD.  Each with its own server name.  Do I need a separate build definition for each environment or is there a way to use one build definition?
3. Anything useful in using powershell somehow?

Here is SSIS.MSBuild.proj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Project  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
          DefaultTargets="SSISBuild;SSISDeploy">
  <!--Requires a property called $(SSISProj) to be defined when this script is called-->
  <UsingTask TaskName="DeploymentFileCompilerTask" AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Build.dll" />
  <Target Name="SSISBuild" Condition="'$(SSISProj)' != ''">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SSISProjPath>$(SSISProj)\$(SSISProj).dtproj</SSISProjPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="**************Building SSIS project: $(SSISProjPath) for configuration: $(CONFIGURATION)**************" />
    <DeploymentFileCompilerTask
      InputProject="$(SSISProjPath)"
      Configuration="$(CONFIGURATION)"
      ProtectionLevel="DontSaveSensitive">
    </DeploymentFileCompilerTask>
  </Target>

  <UsingTask TaskName="DeployProjectToCatalogTask" AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Build.dll" />
  <Target Name="SSISDeploy" Condition="'$(SSISProj)' != ''">
    <Message Text="**************Publishing SSIS project: $(SSISProj) to: $(SSISServer) to folder: $(PROJECTNAME)**************" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ISPac>$(SSISProj)\bin\$(CONFIGURATION)\$(SSISProj).ispac</ISPac>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <DeployProjectToCatalogTask
          DeploymentFile="$(ISPac)"
          Instance="$(SSISServer)"
          Folder="$(PROJECTNAME)"
          CreateFolder="true"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

***EDIT*** I tried adding some MSBuild Arguments to the TFS Build Definition.  I tried various combinations of arguments, some with quotes, some without.  I couldn't get it to work.

```
"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Buildssis\SSIS.MSBuild.proj" /t:SSISBuild,SSISDeploy /p:SSISProj="MySSISProject",Configuration="SIT",SSISServer="AB-CDE-FGH-I1\DEV",ProjectName="MySSISProject"
```

But I always get this error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: C:\Users\me\Desktop\Buildssis\SSIS.MSBuild.proj

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

Comment: Sorry, as far as I know there is no proper support for SSIS in MSBuild.  I have simply used devenv.exe to do the builds.  This means VS needs to be installed on the server, but that's what you want for CI anyway.  As for deployment, do not use a CI tool for that.  Check out Release Management (Microsoft's product) or OctopusDeploy for starters.  They will allow you to specify different values for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the MSBUILD error, in the process section of your build definition:

- the path to the proj file goes into the section "2. Build > 1. Projects"
- the MSBUILD switches go in the field named "2. Build > 5. Advanced > MSBUILD Arguments".

[image]